# Easy way to find x y coordinates on MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, android-monkey

I am using MonkeyRunner to test my very broad application and running many different scripts on my devices. However it is taking a long time to figure out where the x/y coordinates are on every touch of the screen. I tried using this nice plugin http://blogs.wittwer.fr/whiler/2011/07/01/editeur-monkeyrunner/
but its coordinates are not accurate enough....Is there any app I can install that will give me a toast for the coordinates I need?

```
device.touch(225, 182, "DOWN_AND_UP")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates of every touch can be obtained using **Settings -> Developer options -> Pointer location**, but perhaps you don't need the coordinates at all. Take a look at http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/05/androidviewclient-q.html which describes how you can use *View IDs* to obtain coordinates and send events.

Answer (score 0):

This is great working on a voice app that to push a button without modifying the app itself. On a galaxy s 3 (phone it is for) you must enable developer options by going to settings > more > about device > build number and tap multiple times until developer options are enabled then go back a screen to developer options.